# Replacing one specific factor based on another factor

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, factors

R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)

Hello all, so I have been working with some baseball data and I've been struggling replacing one factor based on another...
Suppose I have:

```
Names <- c("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5")
batHand <- c("L", "S", "L","S", "R")
stats <- c(1, 2, 0, 1, 1)
pitchHand <- c("R", "L", "R", "R", "L")
baseballdf <- data.frame(Names, batHand, Stats, pitchHand)
```

And I want to switch all the S's to the opposite of the pitchHand, so it would look like this:

```
Names <- c("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5")
batHand <- c("L", "R", "L","L", "R")
stats <- c(1, 2, 0, 1, 1)
pitchHand <- c("R", "L", "R", "R", "L")
baseballdf2 <- data.frame(Names, batHand, Stats, pitchHand)
```

(Real data frame is 40,000+ rows so simply switching them manually will not work)

I've mainly been using dplyr and have tried numerous variations of mutate, replace, case_when and if_else but can't quite figure it out.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way with nested `ifelse`:

```
baseballdf %>% 
  mutate(batHand = ifelse(batHand != "S", batHand, ifelse(pitchHand == "R", "L", "R")))
```

`case_when` might be more readable, but we need to change the column to `character` first:

```
baseballdf %>%
  mutate(
    batHand = as.character(batHand),
    batHand = case_when(
      batHand != "S" ~ batHand,
      pitchHand == "R" ~ "L",
      pitchHand == "L" ~ "R"
  ))
```

Comment: Both worked!  Thanks @Gregor!  I was on the right track for both of them at one point or another but messing up the syntax